Are the following algebraic sets isomorphic over the complex numbers?
I am interested in determining which of the following algebraic sets are isomorphic over the complex numbers:

$\mathbb{A}^1$
$Z(xy) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$
$Z(x^2 + y^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$
$Z(y^2 - x^3 - x^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$
$Z(x^2 - y^3) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$
$Z(y - x^2, z - x^3) \subset \mathbb{A}^3$

I understand that some verifications can be done by considering local properties (as shown here), but I would like a solution that uses only algebraic considerations regarding coordinate rings or basic facts about morphisms—such as considering the correspondence between morphisms and $k$-algebra homomorphisms of the coordinate rings.
Of course, an immediate argument for some cases is to use irreducibility. Here is my progress on the problem so far:

Clearly, $\mathbb{A}^1$ cannot be isomorphic to $Z(xy)$ or $Z(x^2 + y^2)$, as these sets are reducible.

Note that
$$
   Z(y - x^2, z - x^3) = \{(t, t^2, t^3) \mid t \in \mathbb{C}\}.
   $$
The map $t \mapsto (t, t^2, t^3)$ defines an isomorphism from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to $Z(y - x^2, z - x^3)$.

We can also use irreducibility to verify that $Z(x^2 - y^3)$ and $Z(y^2 - x^3 - x^2)$, each defined by an irreducible polynomial and thus irreducible, are not isomorphic to $Z(xy)$ or $Z(x^2 + y^2)$.


I would appreciate insights on how to approach proving (or disproving) isomorphisms for the remaining pairs, especially if there are ways to leverage algebraic properties of the coordinate rings in a straightforward manner. Thank you in advance!
